# How to make pages look in QTextEdit or QPlainTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtextedit, qplaintextedit

I am trying to make the look of pages in `QTextEdit` or using it to do so.

Each page has a limited number of lines per page and a limited number of character per line and the first thing is the look and feel of pages.
so I try to use this code.

```
QVBoxLayout *layout =new QVBoxLayout();
ui->scrollArea->setLayout(layout);
ui->scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);

QTextEdit *edit = new QTextEdit("hello world");
edit->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::QSizePolicy::Preferred,QSizePolicy::Preferred);
QTextEdit *edit1 = new QTextEdit("hello world");
edit1->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::QSizePolicy::Preferred,QSizePolicy::Preferred);
QTextEdit *edit2 = new QTextEdit("hello world");
edit2->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::QSizePolicy::Preferred,QSizePolicy::Preferred);
// i added more
layout->addWidget(edit);
layout->addWidget(edit1);
layout->addWidget(edit2);
```

This idea is simple just use scrollbar container and add it vertical layout, and every time I need a page, make a new `QTextEdit` and add it to the vertical layout in the scrollbar.

The problem here is that whenever I add a new page, the `QTextEdit` I add it so too small and the scrollbar never work on it so that the `QTextEdit` be above each other so it makes a bad look.

[image]

So what I make wrong so that the scrollbar not working, and how to make each `QTextEdit` take a good page look which has a good size to give me the look of something like Microsoft word or pdf which have pages.

Also if there is a better idea or a solution to what I am trying to do it will be better if there is an already implemented widget or library have this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to replace the existing layout of the QScrollArea, what you have to do is create a widget, and in that widget set the layout. After that widget you must place it in the QScrollArea through the `setWidget()` method, if you want the height shown to be larger then set a minimum size.

```
QWidget *contentWidget = new QWidget;

QVBoxLayout *layout =new QVBoxLayout(contentWidget);
ui->scrollArea->setWidget(contentWidget);
ui->scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);

QTextEdit *edit = new QTextEdit("hello world");
edit->setMinimumHeight(200);
// create others QTextEdit
layout->addWidget(edit);
// add the QTextEdits
```